# Passing an Object into Dlist

Tags: java

```
/* DListNode1.java */

public class DListNode1 {


  public Object item;
//  public short[][] colorVal;
  public DListNode1 prev;
  public DListNode1 next;


  DListNode1() {
    item = 0;
    prev = null;
    next = null;
  }

  DListNode1(Object i) {
    item = i;
    prev = null;
    next = null;
  }
}
```

```
  /* Double linked list */
public class DList1 {

  protected DListNode1 head;
  protected DListNode1 tail;
  protected long size;

  public DList1() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
  }



  public DList1(Object a) {
    head = new DListNode1();
    tail = head;
    head.item = a;
    size = 1;
  }  
  public DList1(Object a, Object b) {
    head = new DListNode1();
    head.item = a;
    tail = new DListNode1();
    tail.item = b;
    head.next = tail;
    tail.prev = head;
    size = 2;
  }

  public void insertFront(Object i) {
    DListNode1 temp = new DListNode1(i);
    if (size == 0) {
      head = temp;
      tail = temp;
    }
    else {
      temp.next = head;
      head.prev = temp;
      head = temp;
    } size++;  
  }


  public void removeFront() {
    if (size == 0) {
      return;
    }
    else if (size == 1) {
      head = null;
      tail = null;
      size--;
    }
    else {
      head = head.next;
      head.prev = null;
      size--;
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    String result = "[  ";
    DListNode1 current = head;
    while (current != null) {
      result = result + current.item + "  ";
      current = current.next;
    }
    return result + "]";
  }
```

```
public class num{
    public int j; 
    public num() {
      this.j = 34;
    }
   }
```

```
public class testing{
     private DList1 dli;
     private num n;

     public testing(){
     dli = new DList1();
     n = new num();
     dli.insertFront(n);} 
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           testing Jimmy = new testing();
           System.out.printf(" this should be 34 %d\n",Jimmy.dli.head.item.j);// dont' work.
       }
     }
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't do `Jimmy.dli.head.item.j`? It makes perfect sense and yet, it said "j cannot be resolved or is not a field". How to fix it so that it will print `34`? without this line "dli.insertFront(n.j);"

Comment: Who is `Jimmy` anyway? o.O

Comment: `item`'s type is `Object` and `Object` has no field named `j`

Comment: item is n right? isn't n.j = 34?

Comment: IS there a way to access 34?

Answer (score 0):

> item is num right? isn't n.j = 34

Yes, you have created a `num` object and assigned it to `item`. However, `item` is a reference to the `Object` part of `num` only - hence, through this reference, you can only access those members which are part of the `Object` superclass (`num` implicitly inherits from `Object`).

> IS there a way to access 34?

Yes, you can **cast** `Jimmy.dli.head.item` back to `num` to access the `j` member, like `((num)Jimmy.dli.head.item).j`.

However, the proper way to implement this is to make `DListNode1` and `DList1` **generic** instead of using `Object`  as the item element:

```
public class DListNode1 <T> {
  public T item;
  ...

public class DList1 <T> {
  protected DListNode1<T> head;
  protected DListNode1<T> tail;
  ...
```

Wherever you are using `Object` in your `DListNode1` and `DList1` classes, use `T` now.

Then, you can instantiate a type safe `DList1` like

```
DList1<num> dli = new DList1<>();
```

Since `item` is now of type `num`, and not `Object`, you can access its `j` element like you intended:

```
System.out.printf(" this should be 34 %d\n",Jimmy.dli.head.item.j);
```

See also [The Java Tutorials, Lesson: Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

BTW, you should get used to the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) - e.g. class names should start with a capital letter (`Testing` instead of `testing`, `Num` instead of `num`).

Comment: so in the methods I should use T as well? something like public Dlist1(T a, T b) {}

Or insertFront(T i) {}??? Doesn't work though

In the initlization of DListNode() { item = 0;} it said something like int cannot convert to T.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And use `null` instead of `0` (0 works in your case because it is autoboxed into an `Integer` object)